# how to get the pointer of base class in c++

Tags: c++, pointers, overloading

I am trying to implement class minStack to keep track the minimal element of a Stack. Below are my codes. I tried to use the pointer of the base class Stack, since I need to update the original stack, but I do not know how to call it, since it is the pointer of the base class instead of a member of base class.

```
class minStack: public Stack{
private:
    Stack* minS;
public:
    int min()const{
        if(minS->top)
            return minS->top->data;
        return -1;
    }
    minStack(){
        minS = new Stack();
    }
    int pop(){
        if (Stack::this->pop == min()) {   //question here!
            minS->pop();
        }
    }
    void push(int item){
        if(item <= min()){
            minS->push(item);
        }
        Stack::this->push();  //question here!
    }
};
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can call `Stack::pop()` and `Stack::push()` to call the functions of the base class:

```
int pop()
{
    if (Stack::pop() == min()) { minS->pop(); }
}

void push(int item)
{
    if (item <= min())
    {
        minS->push(item);
    }
    Stack::push(item);
}
```

---

An unrelated piece of advice: Usually one would not *derive* from a container in order to make a container adapter such as yours. Typically you'd *compose* your class with members:

```
class min_stack
{
    std::stack<int> stack_;
    std::stack<int> min_;
public:
    int pop() { /* ... */ }
    void push(int n) { /* ... */ }
};
```

Comment: @Kerrek SB I want the base class to pop and push as well, like super in java

Comment: @Kerrek SB It works. Thanks a lot. Sometimes I am confused when should I use inherit and when compose. Can you give me some general suggestion? Thanks!

Comment: @Kerrek SB Also, in java, the codes are as follows, I were trying to translate that: 'code' public class StackWithMin2 extends Stack<Integer> { Stack<Integer> s2;
public StackWithMin2() {
s2 = new Stack<Integer>();}
public void push(int value){ if (value <= min()) {
s2.push(value);
super.push(value); }
public Integer pop() {
int value = super.pop(); if (value == min()) {
s2.pop(); }
return value; }
public int min() {
if (s2.isEmpty()) {
return Integer.MAX_VALUE; } else {
return s2.peek(); }
} }

Comment: @ivory: generally, compose. Public inheritance implies an "is-a" relationship. Private inheritance implies an "is implemented in terms of" relationship. Polymorphic inheritance (with virtual functions) should be used if and only if you genuinely need to decide a type at runtime, and the non-leaf classes should be abstract. If all this is too much to think about, just don't derive and use composition.

Comment: @ivory: I don't know Java. Java is messed up, because it dogmatically forces everything to be a (class-type) object, so you end up with a lot of solutions that feel awkward because they are constrained to fit into this narrow philosophy.